# Is Rhoconnect Rhosync free to use

Tags: ruby, rhodes

- I am developing mobile apps with rhodes  using **Rhoconnect** .
- I don't know is their any licence or it is free to use ...
- I searched complete site of motorola but not get whether it is free or having licence ...
- Is their any other option to sync application data with backend without using Rhoconnect

Answer (score 0):

Rhodes and Rhostudio Eclipse plugin are released under free MIT (AS IS) license. you can verify it by looking at their license files located in their git repos that you can find here: https://github.com/rhomobile

As for Rhoconnect, it comes with free 10 device license, and rest you have to talk to sales department to get quota for your needs.

Comment: Is there any other option without using rhoconnect for making backend syc with local db

Comment: I haven't written b'coz its not free... I only checked sample products code